# How to update state object key value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am declaring dateRangePicker field in component state like below

```
dateRangePicker: {
  selection: {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date(),
    key: 'selection',
  },
}
```

later start date and end date changes as below

```
let startDate = "2019-04-16";
let endDate = "2019-05-16";
```

But, I am not able to update these value in state after following code block

```
this.setState({
  dateRangePicker.selection.startDate : startDate,
  dateRangePicker.selection.endDate : endDate,
})
```

I want to update the start and end date accordingly

Comment: you update the entire object, not a part of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work the way you showed. It should be like this:

```
this.setState(ps=>({
 ...ps,
 dateRangePicker:{
   ...ps.dateRangePicker, // Copy old data
   selection: {
      ...ps.dateRangePicker.selection, // Same here
      startDate: startDate
      endDate: endDate

    },
 }
}))
```

We use functional [form](http://endDate) of `setState`, because you can see at one point we access data from previous state: `ps.selection`

Comment: selection available in dateRangePicker object?

Answer (score 1):

The state is a immutable object, so you can not modified it, but create a new one, so using spread ... expression to create a new state.

Answer (score 1):

> what your'e tryin to acheive is to change the state of a deep/nested
>   object in setState..

```
const startDT = "new start date"
const endDT = "new end date"

this.setState(prevState => ({
 ...prevState,
 dateRangePicker: {
  ...prevState.dateRangePicker,
  selection: {
   ...prevState.dateRangePicker.selection,
    startDate: prevState.startDate = startDT,
    endDate: prevState.endDate = endDT,
  }
 }})
)
```

Or,

```
// copy without reference..
const dateRangePicker = { ...this.state.dateRangePicker }

dateRangePicker.selection = { 
 startDate: startDT,
 endDate: endDT,
}

this.setState({ dateRangePicker })
```